# Prove that $f_a:M\to M,m\mapsto ma$ is an isomorphism whenever it injective iff there is nonzero linear map $f:Ε\to Μ$ with $Ε$ injective.

Tags: ring-theory, modules, projective-module, injective-module

Prove that the following are equivalent for a commutative noetherian ring with identity:

(a) For every nonzero $R$-module $Μ$ there is a nonzero linear map $f:Ε\to Μ$ with $Ε$ injective.

(b) For every nonzero $R$-module $Μ$ and any $a\in R$, the endomorphism $f_a:M\to M,m\mapsto ma$ is an isomorphism whenever it is injective.

My attempt is:

$(b)\Rightarrow(a)$ By [Theorem 2.4.3] in the book *Flat Covers of Modules* by Jinzhong Xu,  for every nonzero $R$-module $Μ$ there is a linear map $f:Ε\to Μ$ with $Ε$ injective.

I only have to prove that the map $f$ is non-zero.  That is where I need help.

Comment: What have you tried? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can do a better job helping you work past it ^_^